# DBCP Datasource invalid Tomcat 8, MySQL, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, mysql-connector, apache-commons-dbcp

I've been fighting with this for a while now... I built a new server and am upgrading an app for current versions. Works fine now in Eclipse. But I can't get the new server right.

Using Tomcat 8.5.8, Ubuntu 16.04 server, OpenJDK 1.8.0_111, mysql-connector-5.1.40, mysql-server 5.7

I'm using the generic Tomcat downloaded in `/opt/tomcat` and the mysql-connector-java.jar is in `/opt/tomcat/lib` - and not in the app's `lib`. Works as a server just fine but I can't seem to connect to the database. However, in Eclipse it does on my dev box.

I have updated the Context resource as per the new Tomcat 8 docs. See below - taken mostly from the docs. At least it's not the same as what I had for Tomcat 7. That generated tons of warnings.

I understand the DBCP implementation changed. And I am pretty sure I am using the new one. I suspect I have the wrong version of a jar somewhere. But it should be pretty vanilla as it's a clean install.

Previously I tried offical Ubuntu Tomcat 8 as installed by apt. But that did the same thing. And had many more strange warnings due to the package seemingly missing stuff.

Any help will be most appreciated.

What I get is this:

```
    24-Nov-2016 16:14:36.870 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.lang.NullPointerException"] with root cause
     javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.lang.NullPointerException"
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(QueryTagSupport.java:285)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doStartTag(QueryTagSupport.java:168)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fquery_005f0(index_jsp.java:269)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(index_jsp.java:231)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:159)
```

Based on this:

```
    <Context docBase="app" path="/" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">

        <Resource name="jdbc/appdb" username="root" password="password"
                  url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/app?autoReconnect=true&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&amp;useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&amp;useSSL=false"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
                  testWhileIdle="true"
                  testOnBorrow="true"
                  testOnReturn="false"
                  validationQuery="SELECT 1"
                  validationInterval="30000"
                  timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
                  maxActive="100"
                  minIdle="10"
                  maxWait="10000"
                  initialSize="10"
                  removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
                  removeAbandoned="true"
                  logAbandoned="true"
                  minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
                  jmxEnabled="true"
                  jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
                        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
                  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        />

    </Context>
```

Comment: Have you tried this example [JNDI Datasource HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example)

Comment: I did but get the same result. It's like the driver is not there? But it is...

Comment: If this is for Tomcat 8, then you are using incorrect attributes for the `<Resource>`. For instance, `maxActive` should be `maxTotal` and `maxWait` should be `maxWaitMillis`. Did you upgrade from Tomcat 7 and just use the existing `<Resource>` from Tomcat 7? Please read through https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html and check each of the attributes.